# Number of elements of an array within a structure

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure

I've declared a structure as follows:

```
Public Structure itemSold  
    public dateTime() as Date  
    public itemPrice() as Currency  
End Structure

Public myItemsSold(365) as itemSold
```

`dateTime()` and `itemPrice()` are dynamic and are re-dimensioned as data is added to them. want to know, is it possible to get the number of elements (length) in the datetime() and itemPrice() array?

Answer (score 2):

First, if they are dynamic then [arrays](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=array%20vb.net) is not the best choice for them.
Use [Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.
Second, to get the length of an array you just use `Array.Length`.
Should you follow my advice and use Lists instead, then use `List.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as easy as just getting the `Length` of the array.

```
Dim dateTimes As Integer = itemSold.dateTime.Length
Dim itemPrices As Integer = itemSold.itemPrice.Length
```

This will do the job I think.

Comment: The defined structure, depending on how the TS names it.

Comment: Ah, it is a declared type, not an instance of the type. So how can you use it to get information on instance members?